# Average distance in a disconnected graph

Tags: graph-theory, average

I can't seem to figure out the formula behind the function `mean_distance` from igraph when `unconnected=TRUE`.

If the output for `distances(n)` is:

```
  0   1   1   2 Inf Inf
  1   0   1   1 Inf Inf
  1   1   0   1 Inf Inf
  2   1   1   0 Inf Inf
Inf Inf Inf Inf   0   1
Inf Inf Inf Inf   1   0
```

Then the result for `mean_distance(n, unconnected=TRUE)` is `1.142857`.

I have read the igraph documentation, but I can't reach the value above doing the math by myself without using the function `mean_distance`.

Can someone tell me the mathematic formula behind this function?

Answer (score 3):

It appears to be returning the average of all *finite* distances between *different* vertices. In other words, the average of all the values in your table that are neither `0` nor `Inf`. There are $14$ of these, of which $12$ are `1` and $2$ are `2`, so the average is $16/14=1.\dot 14285\dot 7$.